# cannot read the data object file for handlebars template using require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js

```
//HTML template
requirejs([
    'handlebars',
    'htmlTemplates/mydiv',
    'text!htmlTemplates/mydiv.html'

    ], 
     function (notUsed0, mydivData, mydivTemplate)
    { 
        console.log(mydivData);  
        var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile (mydivTemplate);       
        $(".mydiv").append(theTemplate(mydivData)); 
 //error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'customerName' of undefined


    }
    );
```

data - mydiv.js

```
{
    customerName: "peter"
}
```

template - mydiv.html

```
<div> Name: {{ customerName }} </div>
```

mydiv is a DIV element inside my index.html's body tag

-----edit-----
also I tried defining a variable inside the function

```
var theData = {customerName:"Shop Page"};
```

now everything works fine, no errors, but the html is still not appending to the DIV with mydiv id in my index.html. Why?

Comment: Are you sticking your view and your template into the same file - because you are calling mydiv twice?

Comment: where am I calling it twice? please check the edit - last line of post

Comment: no, he don't called twice, the first is the .js and the second is the .html

Answer (score 1):

To use `myDiv.js` with `requirejs` you must wrap its contents in a declaration that Require will understand.  Check the documentation at http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defsimple

Change the contents of `myDiv.js` to:

```
define({
    customerName: "peter"
});
```